# Im having trouble with increasing the speed that the prefabs over time (every second)(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The float increases over time but then it doesnt keep it on the one that spawns next so for ex Meteor 1 = -2.5 speed when it gets destroyed then Meteor 2 = -2.5 when it spawns
but my game is making them all spawn at -2 speed
this is the code for the mover itself

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeteorMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = -2f;
    
    
    Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        // Give meteor an initial downward velocity 
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, speed);
        

        WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(1);
        int time = 1;
        while (time > 0)
        {
            speed -= .1f;
            time++;
           //yield return speed;
            yield return wait;
        }
        //yield return speed;
        yield return wait;
    }   
}
```

Then the spawners script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeteorSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject meteorPrefab;
    public float minSpawnDelay = 1f;
    public float maxSpawnDelay = 3f;
    public float spawnXLimit = 6f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Spawn();
    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        // Create a meteor at a random x position
        float random = Random.Range(-spawnXLimit, spawnXLimit);
        Vector3 spawnPos = transform.position + new Vector3(random, 0f, 0f);
        Instantiate(meteorPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        
        Invoke("Spawn", Random.Range(minSpawnDelay, maxSpawnDelay));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you've got the following in your MeteorMover:

```
public float speed = -2f;
```

So as soon as the prefab is created it's speed is set to -2f. You need to get the speed from the last Meteor when it's destroyed and use that speed for the next meteor you instantiate.

Comment: Thanks @AdrAs, but I can't figure out how to find the speed of the meteor when it is destroyed

Comment: It should be something like: `myMeteorMoverGameObject.GetComponent<MeteorMover>().speed`